# How to convert a LINQ query from query syntax to query method

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, entity

Linq and EF4.

I have this Linq query in query syntax I would like convert into query method.

Are you able to do it? I tried more tha 2 hours without success :-(

Thanks for your time

```
CmsContent myContentObj = (from cnt in context.CmsContents
                   from categoy in cnt.CmsCategories
                   where categoy.CategoryId == myCurrentCategoryId && cnt.ContentId == myCurrentContentId
                   select cnt).Single();
```

Comment: It's spelled **syntax** - not "sintax" ....

Comment: thanks marc_s for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-direct translation that I believe performs the same task in much less code:

```
var myContentObj = context.CmsContents.Single(
                        x => x.ContentId == myCurrentContentId && 
                        x.CmsCategories.Any(y => y.CategoryId == myCurrentCategoryId)
                    );
```

Comment: Hi it is working great, also for me it is very readable! thanks

Answer (score 2):

My original answer selected the wrong item.  It's a bit more complicated than what I had (which Ani has posted).  Here's what I believe is an equivalent query however and should perform better:

```
CmsContent myContentObj =
    context.CmsContents
           .Where(cnt => cnt.ContentId == myCurrentId
                      && cnt.CmsCategories
                            .Any(categoy => categoy.CategoryId == myCurrentCategoryId))
           .Single();
```

Comment: hi jeff does NOT work error Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'CmsCategory' to 'CmsContent'

Comment: @GibboK: Ah oops, overlooked what was being selected.  It's actually more like what Ani has.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how the C# compiler actually does it, with some help from .NET Reflector to verify:

```
var myContentObj = context
                   .CmsContents  
                   .SelectMany(cnt => cnt.CmsCategories,
                               (cnt, categoy) => new { cnt, categoy })
                   .Where(a => a.categoy.CategoryId == myCurrentCategoryId
                            && a.cnt.ContentId == myCurrentContentId)
                   .Select(a => a.cnt)
                   .Single();
```

Essentially, the 'nested' `from` clauses results in a `SelectMany` call with a transparent identifier (an anonymous-type instance holding the 'parent' `cnt` and the 'child' `categoy`). The `Where` filter is applied on the anonymous-type instance, and then we do another `Select` projection to get back the  'parent'. The `Single` call was always 'outside' the query expression of course, so it should be obvious how that fits in.

For more information, I suggest reading Jon Skeet's article [How query expressions work](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx).